# Reading Mainframe File Using CP1140

Tags: python

i have an mainframe file that uses cobol comp-3 characters. I am trying to parse and read this file using python. I did research and saw we can use encode="cp1140". I was able to read some of the file but there are still some characters that i cannot understand in the output. I also have a copybook which I am guessing it has the fields embedded inside? Once I can read this file, how can I integrate the copybook fields into the file? I am sorry but very new to decoding/encoding world.

code:

```
file =     r"\\computername\C\mystuff\FTP_Files\Suspense_FTP_Files\11_pymt_bucket\T11111.G3170V00"
    
    
    with open(file,'r', encoding="cp1140") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for row in data:
            print(row.strip("\n"))
```

result:

PP990UNABLE TO LOCATE PAYMENT

Comment: Can you open the file and see what the binary code there is?  It's quite possible something that doesn't translate to ASCII.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie I am able to read the data float values, such as 90.09 or 40.34
these points are getting converted into those results, is there any possible way to translate it using ASCII ?